# Why VS2015 can't find my Raspberry Pi 2 in the Remote Connections dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windowsiot

I have a Raspberry Pi 2, I've followed these documents([LINK1](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupPCRPI.htm) & [LINK2](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupRPI.htm)) to set up my PC and device.

But when I tried to deply my uwp IoT app to this device, VS2015 can't find my device in the Remote Connections dialog, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish the IDE can find your IoT device, it should be in the same network segment, you should have installed the [Windows 10 IoT Core tools](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm), there is a tool called **Windows IoT Core Watcher**, it's helpful to list all available Windows IoT Core devices in the internal network.

And we need to double check if the remote debugger has been launched on your Windows IoT Core device, use the `tlist` command to list all the running processes from powershell. There should be two instances of msvsmon.exe running on the device. See **Troubleshooting Visual Studio Remote Debugger** section in [here](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, yes, finally I used that tool to find my raspberry Pi 2 and remote debugging is working now!